Output motion vector and depth on HDRP unity with Jitter (like TAA halton sequence)
I'm currently working on a project to implement the DLSS2.0.
So I need to output the motion vector and depth and jitter (x,y) from the HDRP Unity engine.
It seems HDRP is the only engine which supports DLSS upscaling.
I only find some articles to dump information in built-in engine.
like 在Unity built-in RP中擷取motion vector (in Chinese)
or Outputting Motion Vectors data to image
But I can't find the way to do the same trick in HDRP pipeline.
Does anyone have any idea how to do it?
I have tried to dump the motion vector as the first link describes, but no luck.
CaptureFrame uses RenderTexture for src and dest, but HDRP uses RTHandle, and I don't know how to convert RTHandle to RenderTexture.
Material m_Material;
int frameNumber = 0;

public bool IsActive() => m_Material != null && intensity.value > 0f;

// Do not forget to add this post process in the Custom Post Process Orders list (Project Settings > Graphics > HDRP Global Settings).
public override CustomPostProcessInjectionPoint injectionPoint => CustomPostProcessInjectionPoint.AfterPostProcess;

const string kShaderName = "Hidden/Shader/mv_dump3";

public override void Setup()
{
    if (Shader.Find(kShaderName) != null)
        m_Material = new Material(Shader.Find(kShaderName));
    else
        Debug.LogError($"Unable to find shader '{kShaderName}'. Post Process Volume mv_dump3 is unable to load.");
}

public override void Render(CommandBuffer cmd, HDCamera camera, RTHandle source, RTHandle destination)
{
    if (m_Material == null)
        return;
    CaptureFrame(src, dest, m_Material, "D:/" + frameNumber++ + ".exr");
    m_Material.SetFloat("_Intensity", intensity.value);
    m_Material.SetTexture("_MainTex", source);
    HDUtils.DrawFullScreen(cmd, m_Material, destination, shaderPassId: 0);
}
private void CaptureFrame(RenderTexture src, RenderTexture dest, Material shaderProgram, string filepath)
{
    RenderTexture currentFrameTexture = new RenderTexture(Screen.width, Screen.height, 0, RenderTextureFormat.ARGBFloat);
    currentFrameTexture.enableRandomWrite = true;
    currentFrameTexture.Create();
    // render the current frame's render to the new RenderTexture
    Graphics.Blit(src, currentFrameTexture, shaderProgram);

    // save the frame's render to a Texture2D
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(currentFrameTexture.width, currentFrameTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGBAFloat, false);
    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, currentFrameTexture.width, currentFrameTexture.height), 0, 0);
    tex.Apply();

    // save those data to exr file
    byte[] exrBytes = tex.EncodeToEXR();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filepath + ".exr", exrBytes);

    Destroy(tex);

    Graphics.Blit(src, dest);
}

